# Alternative characterization of complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. It is complete if every Cauchy sequence for $d$ on $X$ is convergent.

I've heard an alternative definition of completeness for $(X,d)$: it is complete iff the following condition holds:

Let $\{x_n\}\subset X$ be a sequence of points which leaves every compact set of $X$ (we say $\{x_n\}$ goes to infinity), then $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}d(x,x_n)=\infty}$ for every point $x\in X$.

Is this alternative characterization right? 
Where can I find a proof of the equivalence of the two characterizations?

Thank you!

Comment: A compact metric space is always complete, and in a compact space there is no sequence that eventually leaves each compact set, so the two *are* equivalent for compact metric spaces.

Comment: yes you're right

Answer (score 4):

Consider $X = \mathbb R$ in the discrete metric. Then a set is compact if and only if it is finite. Now, take for example $x_n$ an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. Then $x_n$ leaves eventually every finite subset of $\mathbb R$.

Also note that $d(x,x_n) \to 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, $d$ is the discrete metric.

Comment: Simpler: $x_n=n$. It would be a good idea to note explicitly that $X$ is complete. (But +1.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Right.

Answer (score 0):

They are not alternative (First condition on metric space does not imply second)

Consider $(X,d)$, cone over $(S^1,d_0)$ where for $x\neq y\in S^1$,
$d_0(x,y)=\infty$ That is as a set $X$ is a unit ball in ${\bf
R}^2$. Here $$ d(re^{i\theta },r_2 e^{i\theta_2})=r+r_2 $$ for
$\theta\neq \theta_2$ and $$ d(re^{i\theta },r_2
e^{i\theta_2})=|r-r_2| $$ for $\theta =\theta_2$

Note that $X$ is closed so that it is complete. But
$\{x_n=e^{i\theta_n} \}$ where $\theta_n$ is distinct does not
convergent subsequence since $d(x_n,x_m)=2$ for $n\neq m$ So it is
not in any compact set. But $d(x,x_n)\leq 2$ for all $x\in X$